# How to convert glyphs for printable ASCII characters in a TTF font into SVG Path in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, fonts, truetype

I'm trying to take a .ttf font and get a list of path coordinates for each (printable) ascii character in python, I figure the best way to approach this first would be to convert the glyphs to svg format, however I can't find a good way to do this.

Comment: Did you try this library: https://pypi.org/project/fonttools/?

Comment: @EldinurtheKolibri yep, i wasn't able to figure out how to use it, especially not for this

Comment: It doesn't sound easy. I can't help you with this since I don't code that much in python... sorry. You should probably read the docs or consult a local expert.

Comment: @EldinurtheKolibri It's fine, and i have tried reading the docs, and I wouldn't really know where to ask, but thanks for the suggestions